# thrift description file form existing java classes

Tags: serialization, thrift, thrift-protocol

there is a way to generate thrift description file for existing java classes using refletion? Avro has that feature, but i need to use thrift and i have a lot of existing business class in java that i need to serialize in c++ and java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not from the library directly; thrift generates it's own classes and some validation code so that both "ends" (client/server) can inter-operate without error. You should write code to map your business objects to thrift objects.

Comment: Thank for the answer i have seen that. I think that into thrift library there will be some utility code to facilitate this, because in many enterprise java project, already exist some business class. Anyway thanks again for replay

Answer (score 1):

Enter Swift:   https://github.com/facebook/swift/

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/swift
cd swift ; mvn package
```

In particular swift2thrift. Markup your classes as here: https://github.com/facebook/swift/

and run:

```
MY_CLASSES=$HOME/ExampleService/target/ExampleService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  # just an example
cd ~/ExampleService ; mvn compile package && java -cp ~/swift/target/swift2thrift-generator-cli-0.15.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar:$MY_CLASSEScom.facebook.swift.generator.swift2thrift.Main -package net.mycompany ExampleService -map ExampleService path/to/base.thrift -namespace py mycompany.thrift -namespace java net.mycompany.thrift -namespace cpp mycompany
```

outputs Thrift .idls for existsing Java classes.

Also see: [Can generate .thrift files from existing java/scala interfaces and data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649288/can-generate-thrift-files-from-existing-java-scala-interfaces-and-data-types)